# C++ 2D array to function when size is variable

Tags: c++, function, variables, struct

I need to pass 2D array of struct to function.

```
struct Point {  
  int x, y;
  double f, g, h;
  int parentX, parentY;
  int status;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Point grid[fieldX][fieldY];
  void something(grid){}
}
```

How to?

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) so technically you can't even define your array. Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead (as already mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

You have plenty of choices:

Use `std::vector` this makes it super easy:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> Grid;

void something(std::vector<std::vector<Point>> &grid) { ...
```

If you know the size is going to be set at compile time always, use a `std::array`:

```
typedef std::array<std::array<Point, YDimSize>, XDimSize> Grid;
Grid grid;

void something(Grid &grid) { ...
```

Comment: You'd be better off with a single `vector` and some functions for translating 2D coords to an index and vice versa. That way you have a contiguous underlying array and you can still use the `data()` method to pass that array to C style functions.

Comment: @Fibbles, sure, it would also be potentially a minor speed up (for the vector). You could also implement your own 2d vector class that overrides the `operator[]` to make these operations clean. But all of this is a bit too much i think for the OP, who hasn't mentioned C libraries or the need for efficiency. I think simpler is better in this case.